# getting message condition is always true

Tags: javascript, resharper

I'm getting message from resharper as condition is always true for following code

```
if (filters == "answers" || "solution") {

}
```

what's happening here in this code?

Comment: `if (filters == "answers" || filters == "solution") {

}`

Comment: `"solution"` will always be true.

Comment: if (if (filters === "answers" || filters === "solution")

Comment: your second part of the condition will always be satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (filters == "answers" || "solution") {

}
```

In the above code "solution" is true always

So, Change to this

```
  if (filters == "answers" || filters =="solution") {

    }
```

Example

```
If("i")
{

}
```

Above is true always.

So, In your code the second condition returns TRUE always

As per the Boolean  **OR , [Anything with TRUE] is always TRUE**

You have two predicates , So your truth table will be

```
   i/p               o/p
TRUE   FALSE        True
FALSE  TURE         True
FALSE  FALSE         False
TRUE   TRUE         True
```

in your code, You will never get the condition #1 and #3 so, It will be true always

so your code will be true always

Comment: Downvoting with out comment is pet peeve of mine