# Why does this while-loop run infinitely?

Tags: javascript

How come this code runs an infinite loop?
Everything i type in the prompt returns null and I dont know why.

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Du befinner dig hemma i soffan. Det är mörkt utomhus och TVn är påslagen. På soffbordet ser du ett tomt glas och en flaska vodka." + "\n\n" + "Vad vill du göra? Skriv in ditt val:" + "\n" +
  "1. Stäng av TVn" + "\n" + "2. Gå utomhus" + "\n" + "3. Fyll glaset med vodka" + "\n" + "\n" + "4. Avsluta");

while (userChoice != "stäng av tvn" || "gå utomhus" || "fyll glaset med vodka" || "avsluta") {
  alert("Skriv in ditt val som det är skrivet i menyn!")
  userChoice = prompt("Du befinner dig hemma i soffan. Det är mörkt utomhus och TVn är påslagen. På soffbordet ser du ett tomt glas och en flaska vodka." + "\n\n" + "Vad vill du göra? Skriv in ditt val:" + "\n" +
    "1. Stäng av TVn" + "\n" + "2. Gå utomhus" + "\n" + "3. Fyll glaset med vodka" + "\n" + "\n" + "4. Avsluta");

  console.log(userChoice);
}
```

Comment: Because that's not how you check "if this is not one of the specified values". `userChoice != "abc" && userChoice != "def" && ...`

Comment: Strings are truthy, so those OR conditions will always be true.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ... non-empty strings.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir True, but he's comparing against non-empty literals, so I figured that wasn't relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting message condition is always true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498885/getting-message-condition-is-always-true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-empty `string` is a `truthy` value so the `OR` conditions will be true. That's why you got a infinite loop. You need to set `userChoice !=` before every string.

Moreover, you should use `AND` operators to check that the `userChoice` is none of the expected values.

```
while (userChoice != "stäng av tvn" && userChoice != "gå utomhus" && "fyll glaset med vodka" && userChoice != "avsluta")
```

Comment: I switched the `OR` to `AND` and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: You need more than switching the OR to AND, check my edit.